# converting pdf file to excel with images in the table using python

Tags: python, tabula

The pdf files that I need to convert will have images in table. I want to convert the text as well as the images in tables of pdf to excel. Please suggest me suitable libraries for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PikePDF](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf) to extract the images from the pdf:

```
from pikepdf import Pdf, PdfImage

filename = "sample.pdf"
example = Pdf.open(filename)

for i, page in enumerate(example.pages):
    for j, (name, raw_image) in enumerate(page.images.items()):
        image = PdfImage(raw_image)
        out = image.extract_to(fileprefix=f"{filename}-page{i:03}-img{j:03}")
```

After extracting the image you can then use [OCR](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/text-extraction-from-a-table-image-using-pytesseract-and-opencv-3342870691ae) to convert the image to a table

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a script that will read and detect character and excel cells. You may be able to do that with open-cv and the build-in character recognition tool, but I don't know how easy it would be. Another way I could think of is to make an ML model that will recognise excel sheets from an image. This is really hard though and requires a lot of experience.