# Image Processing from PDF to excel

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, image-processing, export-to-excel

I have a pdf file which holds a few tables containing different colors instead of RGB values.

I have been tasked to fetch RGB value from each row and transition the information into excel (following similar table format).

Can someone please point me in the right direction. since i have been through hell in finding the solution. I have also tried to using camelot library for reading the pdf file but unfortunately camelot does not recognize the colors.
[image]

Comment: I think this is a good start, eventually you will need to use OCR to get the text inside the images.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67033473/converting-pdf-file-to-excel-with-images-in-the-table-using-python

Comment: Thanks @Batselot for sharing this, it was very helpful. If you know more literature please do share with me.

Comment: Thanks @K J, do you have any literature or sample code to share?